# Web browsing over SSH

Tags: browser, ssh, firewall

I have something of a difficult situation : our company has a webserver in a remote data center that's, at the moment, only accessible by SSH and the firewall is not easily modifiable because the techs at the data center are unreliable and unreachable lately (not my choice of data center, and switching is not an option at the moment).  Are there any browsers or plugins out there that will let me browse over an SSH connection ?  I can browse with links and lynx on the SSH command line, but that doesn't give me access to various functionality I need, and it's too hard to find things in the web application running on a Tomcat server on the box that I need access to.  Does anybody have any suggestions ? We're already working on getting direct access to the web application by having the firewall opened up, but I need something better in the mean time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, you need to create a SSH Tunnel. Remember to **clear the text** in `No Proxy for`

Second, simply browse your website by entering `http://localhost`

Answer (score 10):

You might have interest in SSH port forwarding.  The SSH client listens on a specified port, then forwards all data sent to that port to the remote server.

For example, on your machine, you would run:

```
ssh -L 12345:localhost:80 myserver.example.com
```

This will SSH to myserver.example.com, and start listening on port 12345 on your machine.  Then you would open a web browser and go to `http://localhost:12345/`.  Your SSH client will forward this to the remote server and connect to localhost:80 on that end.  The response will be sent back to you.

You can try reading [this article](http://www.medicalnerds.com/port-forwarding-with-sshputty/) that describes the process in a little more detail.

Comment: Is there any way to make a tunnel for all of ports instead of using just one port forwarding (`12345:80`)?

Comment: @BenyaminJafari As far as I know, you have to specify every port individually. Perhaps you would be better served by a VPN? Tailscale is easy to set up and will give you direct access to the remote machine.

Comment: Thank you for your response

Answer (score 4):

You could set up a proxy on one of the internal servers that translates SSH to HTTP. This would be useful if you have difficulty changing the firewalls but can manage servers inside.

---

With some more thoughts and answers here, I like `Stephen`'s trick of port forwarding.
It is more elegant(+1). I'd suggest a couple of more options on the same:

```
ssh -f -N -L 12345:localhost:80 myserver.example.com
```

- `-f` will force ssh to run as a daemon
- `-N` will disallow ssh from executing remote commands (forward port only)